# PHP sorting array of objects by object's property value

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I have an array of objects like the image given below. I would like to sort the array elements by the `'earned'` key (descending order). I tried with usort but ended up with getting errors like
 `usort expects parameter 1 to be array, object given.` Cant figure out the problem.

[image]

```
 usort($users,function($a,$b) use ($users)
    {
        if ($a->earned == $b->earned) return 0;
        return ($a->earned < $b->earned)?-1:1;
    });
```

Comment: _I tried with usort_ Could you give us a snippet? How did you try?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: code snippet given